# How can I define a cppdepend rule as code smell rule?

Tags: c++, sonarqube, rules, cppdepend

I created a new rule on cppdepend. My cdproj document included the new line as follows

```
<Query Active="True" DisplayList="True" DisplayStat="True" DisplaySelectionView="False" IsCriticalRule="False"><![CDATA[// <Name>Classes must start with an C</Name>
```

How can I make it appear on the sonarQube dashboard as code smell?

Answer (score 0):

When CppDepend is added as an extension of SonarQube, you have to activate all its rules in your quality profile. For that you can follow these steps:

- Create a new sonarqube C++ quality profile.
- Extend this quality profile to add the CppDepend rules.
- Make this new quality profile the default quality profile.